Prove or disprove that $\iint\cos(x+y)$ of the function over region $D= \{(x,y):0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le1\}$ is strictly between $0$ and $1$.
The question is to do this without integrating the function, since we have not learned double integration techniques. Is there a way to do this with the Riemann sums? Thanks

We know that in the region $D$, $0\le\cos(x+y)\le1$. We can then use this fact to set up the following integral:
$$ \iint_D 0 da \le \iint_D \cos(x+y) da \le \iint_D 1 da $$
We can then simply evaluate the outer integrals which gives us:
$$ 0 \le \iint_D \cos(x+y) da \le 1 $$
